# Cordorva-dialog-plugin works on phonegap but not on app release on the play store

Tags: javascript, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap

I am using the cordorva dialog plugin. Please can you decipher what's wrong with this code: It works when previewing on phone gap, on apple iphone and on android but released on the google play store, it isn't working. i am not sure i am using the deviceready event listener right.

```
  function alrt(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady(){

    navigator.notification.alert(
        'Sorry, your record was not found',   //  message
         adismissed,                          // callback
        'Password Reset',                     // title
        'Ok'                                  // buttonName
    );

 }
}


    //  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    //  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

    function adismissed() {
        console.log();
    }
```

Comment: A lot of times if stuff is not working in store, it has to do with permissions. Have you set all permissions you need for your app?

Comment: I would love to check that out, Kevin. Can you show me how to do that or point me to a study on permissions?

Comment: Okay. I have been able to resolve this issue by re-installing cordova-plugin-dialogs.

Comment: glad to hear. Maybe it's for the best to delete this question.

Comment: ok. i will do that. Thanks alot Kevin